# How to order by count in an application BASED ON Oracle Reports

Tags: sql, oracle

I work with an application very similar to Oracle Reports.

I have a report that uses this query:

```
SELECT cod_agencia, 
       To_char(fecha, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MM:SS') FECHA_DISPLAY, 
       valor, 
       Cc_obt_nom_titular_cuenta (1, valor)    Titular, 
       usuario, 
       Pa_nom_usuario (usuario)                NOMBRE, 
       nombre_objeto 
FROM   cc_audit_obj 
WHERE  campo = 'NUM_CUENTA' 
       AND Trunc(fecha) BETWEEN :w_fecha_i AND :w_fecha_f 
       AND cod_agencia = Nvl(:w_agencia, cod_agencia) 
       AND usuario = Nvl(:w_usuario, usuario) 
       AND valor = Nvl(:w_num_cuenta, valor) 
ORDER  BY fecha ASC
```

to generate this report:

[image]

I would like to order these by ocurrences. So in this image, the first Account is correct (10 ocurrences), the bottom one would move to second place (4 ocurrences), and the two in the middle would be last.

How can I do this?

I was just asked to do this and have no experience with the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a **summary column** - function will be `COUNT`, source will be `nombre` column (at least, looks like to me). See if you can set ordering by the summary column in *descending* order.

---

If it doesn't work, you'll have to calculate number of rows per each `nombre`, e.g.

```
SELECT cod_agencia, 
       To_char(fecha, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MM:SS') FECHA_DISPLAY, 
       valor, 
       Cc_obt_nom_titular_cuenta (1, valor)    Titular, 
       usuario, 
       Pa_nom_usuario (usuario)                NOMBRE, 
       nombre_objeto,
       --
       count(*) over (partition by nombre) cnt                 --> this
FROM   cc_audit_obj 
WHERE  campo = 'NUM_CUENTA' 
       AND Trunc(fecha) BETWEEN :w_fecha_i AND :w_fecha_f 
       AND cod_agencia = Nvl(:w_agencia, cod_agencia) 
       AND usuario = Nvl(:w_usuario, usuario) 
       AND valor = Nvl(:w_num_cuenta, valor) 
ORDER  BY cnt desc, fecha ASC;                                 --> and this
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions.  If you want to order by the count for an account:

```
ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cod_agencia) DESC,
         cod_agencia, fecha ASC
```

Comment: just checking,the partition by should be on 'Nombre Del Usuario' right(based on the expected answer)

Comment: @linusRian . . . The image really has nothing to do with the query.  This is based on the question and the query.